# Create JavaScript Quiz Using Dynamically Generated Elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, button, dynamically-generated

**

## How do I assign an answer value to each checkbox?

When viewed, this code produces (2) questions with (4) possible answers to each question. Next to each possible answer is a checkbox. Right now, each checkbox has a value of false, but I would like to tie the value of each checkbox to the possible answer next to it.

Any ideas?

**

JavaScript-------------------------------------------------------------------

```
//JavaScript Quiz
//Questions and answers - multi-dimensional array.
var quizBank = [
["What object runs code continously until an exit condition is met?", "Loop", "Array","Function","Object"],
["Inside which HTML element do we put JavaScript?","javascript",
"js","scripting","script"]
];

//Adds ordered list, list items, and check-boxes. Iterates through array questions and answers.
function printQuiz(quiz) {
var check = "<input type='checkbox' id= 'response' name='response' label='response'>";
    var listHTML = "<ol>"
    for(i = 0; i < quiz.length; i++){
    listHTML += "<li>" + (i + 1) +": " + quiz[i][0] + "</li>" +
  "<li>" + check + quiz[i][1] + "</li>" +
  "<li>" + check + quiz[i][2] + "</li>" +
  "<li>" + check + quiz[i][3] + "</li>" + 
  "<li>" + check + quiz[i][4] + "</li>";
  }
  listHTML += "<ol>";
  return listHTML;
}
//prints printQuiz function to document
document.getElementById("quiz").innerHTML = printQuiz(quizBank);

/* Accessing the values of the checkboxes */
/* First get the ol's li elements under #quiz */
var listItems = document.getElementById("quiz").childNodes[0].childNodes;

/* Iterate through them and look inside for the input */
listItems.forEach(function(element) {

  if (element.childNodes.length > 1) {
   // of the li's who have more than 1 child nodes, the first child node is the checkbox input.
   var checkbox = element.childNodes[0];
   console.log(checkbox.checked);

    });
```

HTML-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<div>
<h1>
Quiz: Programming Concepts
</h1>
<div id="quiz"></div>
</div>
```

CSS------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
li {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is add a "value" attribute to your input element, whose value will be the response corresponding to that checkbox...
(See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox )

Comment: I am looking for a way to "dynamically" add unique values to each dynamically generated check box.

Comment: So I was thinking of something like:
function check(value) {
  return "<input type='checkbox' value=' + value + "' name='response'>"

Comment: So I was thinking of something like:
`function check(value) {
  return "<input type='checkbox' value=' + value + "' name='response'>"
}
function printQuiz(quiz) {
  for (i=0; i < quiz.length; i++ ) {
    listItem += "<li>" + check(quiz[i][1]) + quiz[i][1] + "</li>";
  }
  return listItem;
}`